# not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello I am starting with Android developing. I am just modifying with Android Studio an open source example.

I have only modified string.xml and some .png files. In the Android simulator it works perfect but when I try to generate the signed Apk file I receive two errors with similar description.

This is one of them (the line is marking with *):

> Error:(33) Error: @id/linear_adview is not a sibling in the same
>   RelativeLayout [Not Sibling]

Comment: Please share .xml file

Comment: Please provide your xml layout

Comment: First of all you have to remove "+" from

This

android:layout_above="@+id/linear_adview"

To

android:layout_above="@id/linear_adview"

Comment: No useful information given. Provide full xml files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_content_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
 <LinearLayout`enter code here`
        android:id="@+id/linear_adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view_editimg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"

 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/sticker_recycler_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear_adview">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/sticker_framelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/linear_adview">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/pic_edit_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/background"

                    />

                <include
                    layout="@layout/text_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </FrameLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/sticker_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smoke_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/smoke"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/share_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/share"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`
`
```

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayout with `android:id="@+id/sticker_framelayout"` isn't a direct sibling of LinearLayout with `android:id="@+id/linear_adview"` and that's why you can't use `android:layout_below="@id/linear_adview"` in it. Actually you can merge RelativeLayout and FrameLayout into one view:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sticker_recycler_view"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear_adview">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sticker_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear_adview">

(...)

        </FrameLayout>
```

to

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sticker_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/sticker_recycler_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear_adview">

(...)

</FrameLayout>
```